# Position div with background below another

Tags: html, css

I have the following structure in html5:

```
html
 - body
   - header
   - #wrapper
   - aside nav
   - footer
```

The header has 2 big divs with background images, one being logo and another being a sub logo.

The nav bar also has background image, and I just added a background to my wrapper, it needs to have a background image because the image needs to expand with the contents inside the wrapper. The wrapper also is positioned at margin-top : -105px so that a portion of the wrappers background goes under the logo and sublogo, since both of those are not 100% wide, the wrappers background shows on the sides, much like a paper page.

My problem is that the wrapper is at this moment, on top of logo and sublogo. I have tried adding a z-index of 10 to my header and z-index of -1 to the wrapper, but no luck.

What can I try to make the wrappers background image go behind the header?

Thank you.

Comment: Please can you show actual HTML mark-up, and your CSS? Ideally post a simple [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is a problematic version : http://jsfiddle.net/gewjP/1/ and here http://jsfiddle.net/gewjP/2/ with the fix by bookcasey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`z-index` only works on elements that are `positions:relative` , `absolute`, or `fixed`.

Add `position:relative;` and a `z-index` to the logo and sub-logo .

Comment: Thank you. For future reference : http://jsfiddle.net/gewjP/1/ is the sample without your fix, and http://jsfiddle.net/gewjP/2/ is with the fix.